# Lightning Input combo-box with new attribute role not working in my org

Tags: picklist, lightning-combobox, spring-20

Trying to implement the new spring release update:
[image]

b) The lightning-input component receives a new attribute called role, enabling the creation of accessible combo boxes. Check out the below example showcasing the creation of combo boxes:

Instead of using lightning combo-box tried using lightning-input type text and role-combobox:

this was my earlier code:
[image]
I change it to this code:
[image]

But now my option is just displayed as a text field:
Not picklist field with required fields.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please add your code in?

Comment: @prem22 Hi yes I had added the code but not visible due to some reason.Modified and added the screenshots. Please check.

Comment: I see, I actually tried implementing it too, it seems to not work, maybe they are not officially release? As the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example does not even document them. I even tried deploying by changing the component's XML version to 60.0 and sfdx-project.json version to 60.0. I only included, role, type, label and options for the lightning-input tag.

Comment: @prem22 Thanks I will wait for the update then.